# SQL server in VS code for beginners

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I have following problem. I want to learn SQL. I have already done few tutorials. Now I would like to run my first SQL file in VS Code.

I have simple sql file saved in the same folder as showids.csv:

```
SELECT contentid
FROM showids
```

Now I want to run my script. I click Execute query -> Create connection profile -> Now I am lost. Could you help me, what should I do here? Or even recommend me some step-by-step guide for someone, who knows nothing about SQL server or ADO.NET? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well you need to connect to a database server or a database file to run your query. Do you have either of those? Where is the table `showids` stored? You'll need to connect to the server that has that data. _Also_ "sql" is a language not  technology. You'll have to connect to a product like SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc. to actually run SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't use csv as database files. It sounds like you don't even have it installed?

You could query a csv using an oledb connection string if you want to use C#/Powershell, but for learning I would suggest installing the express or developer edition of SQL Server and mounting one of Microsoft's sample databases.

Then you can use the extension in vscode to query your local database.